# is it possible to do transition animations when changing views in the same activity?

Tags: android

Suppose I have 2 XML files and my activity will setContentView the appropriate one based on some button press from the user. Is it possible to change the transition animation for the changing of content view?

So far I see super.overridePendingTransition() which is suitable for starting new activities, however my example does not start a new activity, it just changes the layout in the current one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Mathias Lin has explained it very well.

You can always use default stock animations supplied by Android framework.

Heres an example code:

```
boolean isFirstXml=evaluatingConditionFunction();
LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflator.inflate(isFirstXml?R.layout.myfirstxml:R.layout.myseconxml, null, false);
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
setContentView(view);
```

Call this from any of your activity which holds your Parent View.

For custom animations you can visit developer docs. Heres the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) link.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can apply an animation on almost any view you like. Just via `view.startAnimation(animation);`

Take the outer viewgroup of your respective layout (content view) and apply the animation to it. Depending what kind of animation you want to do, it might make sense to inflate/load both layouts but hide one of them and then swap. Please specify what kind of transition you have in mind.

For example: if you do an alpha transition, you would run the alphaAnimation on the current layout, when when the animation ends (AnimationListener), you set the content view to the new layout, and fade the content back in, via another alphaAnimation.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is using ViewFlipper: it is a FrameLayout, that can do animations when changing the views.

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/[your_id_here]"
    android:inAnimation="..."
    android:outAnimation="..."
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            <!--Your first layout -->
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            <!--Your second layout -->
        </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Then, switch the views with `setDisplayedChild(int)` or `showNext()` or `showPrevious`. If you want to have different animation for left and right movement, you have to set `inAnimation` and `outAnimation` in the code before transition.

More complete example is [here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html).

Comment: Thank you. It's much simpler than starting the second activity with animation that I did using `oldActivity.startActivity(newActivityIntent); oldActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);`